# WP shortcode is ignoring passed value

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

WP_Query in shortcode ignoring passed value

Been trying to get this to work for hours. No matter what I do WP uses the default value and ignores values passed into the function.

```
// Add Shortcode
function ima_featured_member( $atts ) {

    // Attributes
    $attributes = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'numb' => '1',
        ),
        $atts,
        'featured'
    );

    $dirloop = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type' => 'member', 
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => $attributes['numb'],
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array (
                'relation' => 'AND',
               array (
                    'key'   => 'elc_member_featured',   
                    'value'  => '1',
                    'compare' => '=='
                )
            )
        ));

        if ($dirloop->have_posts())
        {
            $output = "\n";
            while ( $dirloop->have_posts() ) : $dirloop->the_post(); 

                    $output .= ''.get_the_title().'';

             endwhile;
            $output .= "\n";
        } 
        else
        { 
            $output = "nothing";
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();

        return $output;

}
add_shortcode( 'featured', 'ima_featured_member' );
```

[featured = '2'] doesn't pass. No errors, no warnings, just doesn't work. Any help or insite is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shortcode_atts` portion of the function seems fine.

But the correct way to call the shortcode with the parameter `numb` being `2` would be:

`[featured numb='2']`

and not

`[featured = '2']`

Comment: Ya, I see somebody already accepted your answer or I would have. Don't know why I missed that, concentrating on the function being the issue I guess.

Answer (score 1):

There are few changes that you need to make to this for work.

Change the following code:

```
$attributes = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'numb' => '1',
    ),
    $atts,
    'featured'
);
```

To

```
$attributes = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'numb' => '1',
    ),
    $attributes,
    'featured'
);
```

Also for shortcode to fetch 2 posts, you should write shortcode as following:

```
[featured numb='2']
```

This should work for you.